# AWS Lambda Java, write to S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am creating an AWS Lambda function that is runned monthly. Each month process some data and write that back to S3 Bucket.

Do you know how you can you write a file from AWS Lambda Java to a S3 bucket?

Comment: You can refer to aws sample at [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you can write a file to S3 from any Java application. Use the [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to create a text file in S3 bucket and take a reference of the following code to update the file contents as per your requirement.

```
AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client();
/**
 * @param bucketName
 *            The name of the bucket to place the new object in.
 * @param key
 *            The key of the object to create.
 * @param content
 *            The String to encode
 */
client.putObject("**Bucket Name**", "**File Name to write**", "updated string contents");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using the [AWS Kinesis FireHose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/) service that allows to send data as strings from the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/).
The service will write the files for you, aggregate events, and even compress the files with timestamps.

Comment: Kinesis seems overkill to me to just publish a monthly single file to S3. Why not just using aws SDK with an IAM role attached to your lambda function?

Comment: Sure you could just use the SDK to write a file from string. I dont know which amount of data do you have, it might be a problem storing everything in memory and then dumping as a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try{
            // Create new file
            Util._logger.log(" Creating file transfer ");

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            //Writing in file
            stringBuilder.append('Data you want to write in file');

            // Upload file
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes(Constants.UTF_8));
            s3Client.putObject(dstBucket, uploadFileName, inputStream, new ObjectMetadata());

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, " +
                    "which means your request made it " + 
                    "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error " +
                    "response for some reason.");
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
            Util._logger.log(Constants.EXCEPTION_ERROR + ase.getMessage());
            ase.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, " +
                        "which means the client encountered " +
                        "an internal error while trying to " +
                        " communicate with S3, " +
                        "such as not being able to access the network.");
                System.out.println(Constants.EXCEPTION_ERROR + ace.getMessage());
                Util._logger.log(Constants.EXCEPTION_ERROR + ace.getMessage());
                ace.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                Util._logger.log(Constants.EXCEPTION_ERROR + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample from official Git repo

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/master/sample-apps/s3-java/src/main/java/example/Handler.java